# Java chat client jtextfield vs jtextarea

Tags: java, user-interface, jtextfield, jtextarea

I am writting a simple server chat client using gui to make the chat box and so on. I am simply wondering if I should use jtextarea instead of jtextfield if someone wants to write a long message since jtextfield does not allow word wrap.

Does it matter if I use jtextarea of jtextfield or is there a specific reason not to use jtextarea as my input box?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess:

- You'll probably need both a JTextField *and* a JTextArea (or other multi-line text component).
- The JTextField would be for the user to type in their chat messages to be sent. It would be editable.
- and the JTextArea would show the incoming chats as well as the chats the user has sent. It would not be editable.
- Consider placing the JTextArea in a JScrollPane
- Consider placing both in a BorderLayout-using container with the JScrollPane that holds the JTextArea placed in the CENTER position and the JTextField in the SOUTH position.

Comment: I have it all written out, was simply wondering what you all would suggest to write :), thank you for your opinion

Comment: @LittleChild: yep, that could work well since you could use different colors or fonts for different chatters.

Comment: @KurtE: I would suggest writing code, any code. Not to be glib, but you need to write out requirements and then try to implement them one step at a time in code.

Comment: @KurtE Then go for `JTextPane`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels is right. If your requirements are not well-understood, you will end up with a lot of bugs. Also, make sure they are thorough and don't change your mind midway because that will also cause more bugs. `Changing and improperly understood specs are the major cause of bugs`

Answer (score 1):

A JTextField is a little easier to work with. You can add an ActionListener to it so that when the user hits enter the Action can be invoked an the message will be sent. Of course you can still have a "Send" JButton. the user can click on as well.

With a JTextArea, the Enter key will add a new line, so it you want the user to be able to sent the text when Enter is used you will need to customize the processing, maybe by using Key Bindings. I would prefer the text area because I like to see as much of the text as possible, like I am doing now as I repond to this question.

Answer (score 1):

From oracle docs and personal experience, the JTextField makes life a lot easier as the ActionEventListener is set by default so the actions(characters or text) set in the field are copied to the JTextArea which is like a log of activity carried out in the field.

So the ball is in your court. You can use it JTextField together with JTextArea or JTextArea alone and write the listener class to suit you purpose and certainerly added a listenable event e.g a button.

Besides, always specify the size of the field to avoid layout issues that may compromise the Ui of your application as there is always a dynamic resizing if the size is not specified out rightly.